# Get parameter custom mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I want to write many GET handlers that receive an ID for an object,

```
site.com/controller/Action1/1234
site.com/controller/Action2/1234
site.com/controller/Action3/1234
```

I would like to write the code that fetches the complex object from the DB just once:

```
class ComplexObject
{
    public string str1 { get; set; }
    public string str2 { get; set; }
}

ComplexObject GetFromId(string id)
{
    ComplexObject x = Database.GetById(id);

    if (x == null)
    {
        return Http404();
    }

    return x;
}
```

and then just use the object directly:

```
[Route("/[controller]/[action]/{message}")]
[HttpGet]
public string Action1(ComplexObject message)
{
    return message.str1;
}

[Route("/[controller]/[action]/{message}")]
[HttpGet]
public string Action2(ComplexObject message)
{
    return message.str1;
}

[Route("/[controller]/[action]/{message}")]
[HttpGet]
public string Action3(ComplexObject message)
{
    return message.str1;
}
```

And that all of my handlers will just get the object, and won't have to check whether the ID is correct, etc.

How is that possible?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this since you'd be delegating a lot of the work into a custom model binder which feels really odd to me.

Comment: Just want to understand, you want to write one endpoint to return any object by ID and object name?

Comment: All of this is documented in the official docs by the way... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @Marius Hi, I want to write many endpoints that do different things, but all are going to use the object. Imagine something controlling a car. You would have "drive" and "stop" and "turn", all receiving the car's ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0) describe exactly how you can bind route parameters to a complex object from a database using a custom model binder.

Here's their example model binder:

```
public class AuthorEntityBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly AuthorContext _context;

    public AuthorEntityBinder(AuthorContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

        // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        // Check if the argument value is null or empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        if (!int.TryParse(value, out var id))
        {
            // Non-integer arguments result in model state errors
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                modelName, "Author Id must be an integer.");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Model will be null if not found, including for
        // out of range id values (0, -3, etc.)
        var model = _context.Authors.Find(id);
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And then there are various ways to use this new model binder. One is to add an attribute on the model itself:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(AuthorEntityBinder))]
public class Author
{
    // snip
}
```

Another is to use an attribute on the action parameters:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetById([ModelBinder(Name = "id")] Author author)
{
    // snip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why one would want to do what you are proposing, but it unnecessarily overcomplicates things and causes dependencies on the model binder.

Here is how I would implement this:

Have a class that manages your complex object and hide it behind an interface, the inject it into the controller:

```
public interface IComplexObjectManager 
{
    ComplexObject GetFromId(string id);
}

public class ComplexObjectManager : IComplexObjectManager 
{
    private readonly Database _database;
    
    public ComplexObjectManager(Database database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public ComplexObject GetFromId(string id)
    {
        ComplexObject x = _database.GetById(id);            
        return x;
    }
}

[ApiController]
public class ComplexObjectController
{
    public ComplexObjectController(IComplexObjectManager complexObjectManager)
    {
        ObjectManager = complexObjectManager;
    }

    public IComplexObjectManager ObjectManager { get; }
}
```

Then consume it in your method, changing the return type to an action result:

```
[Route("/[controller]/[action]/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Action1(string id)
{
    var obj = ObjectManager.GetFromId(id);
    if(obj != null)
        return Ok(obj.str1);
    else
        return NotFound();
}
```

Make sure to handle the response accordingly.

This approach decouples things (further abstraction can be added for `Database`), and allows for injection and unit testing.

Please check the code for consistency. I wrote this in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not doing the exactly thing that you are asking but i think it can help you. First of all, i'm using `BaseController` for it because you can filter your all actions before they are getting executed.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    #region /*IoC*/
    public BaseViewModel baseViewModel;
    public IUnitOfWork<Product> unitOfWorkProductForCart;
    #endregion

    #region /*ctor*/
    public BaseController(IUnitOfWork<Product> unitOfWorkProductForCart)
    {
        this.unitOfWorkProduct = unitOfWorkProduct;
    }
    #endregion

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["controller"];
        string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"];
        if (actionName == "ProductDetails")
        {
            var urlParameters = filterContext.ActionArguments;
            if (urlParameters.Count != 0)
            {
                var isThatSlug = urlParameters.ElementAt(0).Key;
                if (isThatSlug == "slug")
                {
                    var slugCondition = urlParameters.ElementAt(0).Value;
                    var isThatProductExist = unitOfWorkProduct.RepositoryProduct.GetProductBySlugForChecking(slugCondition.ToString());
                    if (isThatProductExist.Count == 0)
                    {
                        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
                            {
                                {"controller","Account"},
                                {"action","NotFound"}
                            });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in that example, i'm controlling the parameters. if it's something like i don't want, it's redirects you to the `NotFound` page.
i hope it can give you a idea